# Display some option when radio button is checked

Tags: combobox, textbox

I want to display some options like textbox, combo boxes, and labels when a radio button is checked.  How can I do that?

Comment: Which language are you using? WHat have you tried so far?

Comment: Help us so that we can help you. You are asking everything.